# Debian dist-upgrade does not upgrade to anything higher than 8.11

Tags: debian, upgrade, dist-upgrade

I have a Debian **8.11** server and I'd like to upgrade it to Debian 9 first and to Debian 10 afterwards.

I did the following:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

All finished with no errors and if I repeat the commands above they say that there are 0 packages to be upgraded. Thus I assume that it went well.

Nonetheless, my system is still **8.11**:

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version
8.11
```

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

What can be the problem? I was trying to follow [Upgrades from Debian 8 (jessie)](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your “sources” so that they refer to `stretch` rather than `jessie`:

```
sudo sed -i s/jessie/stretch/ /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Once that’s done,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

will upgrade to Debian 9.

After rebooting, you can repeat the process, replacing `stretch` with `buster` to upgrade to Debian 10.